# Upload/Download Servlet Server

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, upload, download

I apologize if this might be a somewhat similar question to others out there, but I haven't found the answer that I'm looking for and I'm in a bit of a rush.
 I have followed the tutorial seen [here](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/eclipse-file-upload-servlet-with-apache-common-file-upload) to create a file upload servlet.

But I need to create one that you can also download from and delete from.(by using a file specific key given when first uploading it). While I am still google-ing like crazy and trying to wrap my mind around some of the (very different) tutorials out there, is there anyone out here that can help a noob like me modify the servlet in the tutorial stated above to something I can understand/work with? (I have never used JSP & Servlet before :( )

Comment: Step back. Don't try to find a ready-made solution to cut'n paste without even understanding how it works and what it does. Learn how servlets work, take time to digest the information and practice on simple things, then start implementing the stuff that you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. And I totally agree with you. 99% of the code snippets that I search for are not quite what I am looking for but I manage to understand how to alter them to my needs. However if something were to drop on my lap and was exactly what I needed ... I'm not lazy or disinterested , I'm just in a rush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to finish the server to my needs. 
I used [this](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/667-how-write-servlet-uploads-file-server.html) tutorial for uploads; and [this](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html) tutorial for downloads.
Based on what I learned from the two I managed to create a class for deleting data files from the server:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class DeleteServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements
    javax.servlet.Servlet {
static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final int BUFSIZE = 4096;
private String filePath;
private String filename;

public void init() {
    // the file data.xls is under web application folder
    log(" filepath = "+filePath);
} 

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    filename = request.getParameter("filename");
    System.out.println("filename = "+filename);
    filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("") +      File.separator+"data"+File.separator + filename;
    File file = new File(filePath);
    file.delete();
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/deleted.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
}
```

Next is my upload.jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
Upload----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<form method="post" action="UploadServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Select file to upload:
<input type="file" name="dataFile" id="fileChooser"/><br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
Download--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------
<form action="DownloadServlet" method="get">
    File Name: <input type="text" name="filename"/>
<input type="submit" value="Download" />
<a href="DownloadServlet"></a>
</form>
Delete----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------
<form action="DeleteServlet" method="get">
    File Name: <input type="text" name="filename"/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
<a href="DownloadServlet"></a>
</form>
```

And finally my web.xml (that might have some leftover code from other server attempts, but it works fine):

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>CodeWeb</display-name>
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>UploadServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.upload.UploadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UploadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>upload.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>


<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>DownloadServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.upload.DownloadServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/DownloadServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>DeleteServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>DeleteServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.upload.DeleteServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DeleteServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/DeleteServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Hope this helps someone.